# How to have my page templates in sub folder Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a child theme.  In the child theme I would like to have a subfolder for all my page templates, e.g. homepage-template, default-template, etc in /templates.  How can I do this so that wordpress admin menu can still see them when I choose a template for a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you upgrade to WordPress 3.4? This is a native function of 3.4.

See: http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/

Comment: amazing, I didn't know it had been introduced.  Thank you.  Only trouble is the way they have coded it messes up the body_class() output, as instead of < body class="page-template-custom page-templates default-with-2-products-php" > I get < body class="page-template-custompagetemplatesdefault-with-2-products-php" > they are missing a space.

Comment: Weird!!! I haven't run into that yet. Are you sure it's not something in your code? If not, you should submit it as a bug to TRAC.

Comment: well I don't know because I don't edit the body_class function anywhere.  Well only by adding an additional class in there - <?php body_class('no-js');?>

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder with the name ***page-templates*** in your theme folder.
If you have already published pages with templates before having them under this sub-folder, you have to reselect the template page for these pages and click update.