# Calling a page template which is in subdirectory

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a static website in html which is multilanguage. So, I have created several subdirectories depending on the language is selected, this is, "lang" folder for the languages and "fr" folder for francais and "es" for spanish. However, I don't know how to call my template page in WordPress from the control panel for those pages are in another folder.

I have evaluated the issue and I know that is an option available from 3.4 version and you have to create a page-templates folder in the root of your theme, but in my case I'm able only to see my template pages which are in the root of my theme, not from the subdirectory.

Now my directory system is:

wp-content -> themes -> myTheme -> [page-templates folder] - index.php / style.css -> [lang folder] -> [es folder] - about_me.php

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is buying a plugin an option? WPML can give you the options you need.

Comment: @Leonidas Thanks for your answer. I'm not looking for a plugin for translate pages but a way to select from the control panel a template page which is in a subdirectory. Now, I can only do it for pages which are in the root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have my page templates in sub folder Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431426/how-to-have-my-page-templates-in-sub-folder-wordpress)

Comment: @Masiorama Before posting my question I accessed to that post and created a folder called page-templates but I cannot see from my control panel any template page, only those are in the root.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it wasn't clear. Did you try to create a folder "page-templates" and filled it with templates? Can you see templates from there?

Comment: @Masiorama That is, I have created a folder in my theme root called "page-templates" but the control panel does not show me the option to choose any template.

Comment: @Antonio I will give it a try too later, asap, just to find out where the problem is, if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. It seems to me that you have a couple of options.

## 1. Don't use specific page-templates for different languages.

A better way of doing this would be to use the translating options that wordpress already provide.

**To learn more about them you should read at least:**

1. [Translating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)
2. [The function _e()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e)
3. [The function __()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)

## 2. Translate your own way by using arrays or something

You can easily create your own language file in php and write language translations to an array to translate your site.

***Example:***

**File 1 - Language-EN.php**

```
$language_array = array(
  "hello" => "hello",
  "world" => "world"
);
```

**File 2 - Language-NL.php**

```
$language_array = array(
  "hello" => "hallo",
  "world" => "wereld"
);
```

**File 3 - Page-Template.php**

```
$language = "nl";
if($language = "nl")
{
    include 'language-nl.php';
}
elseif ($language = "en")
{
    include 'language-en.php';
}
echo $language["hello"];
```

or (if you are sure the $language variable is set correctly)

```
$language = "nl";
include "language-{$language}.php";
echo $language["hello"];
```

## 3. As you asked: Load template from subdirectory

***Example:***

Create a page template in your themes root directory

**File : page-custom.php**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/

include get_template_directory() . "/subdirectory/subpage-custom.php";
```

Then create a new file in your subdirectory

**File: theme-root/subdirectory/subpage-custom.php**

```
<?php echo "Your code goes here"; ?>
```

Now you can select your page template from the post editor (under attributes)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time! My problem was related with your third point and it works perfectly with get_template_directory. Anyway, I will keep an eye on the other.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress only searches for templates in the theme directory and **one** level below. To do what you want, you'd need to adapt to this. For example:

```
/themes/myTheme
    /templates-en
    /templates-es
    ...
```

Comment: Up to now, my directory is the following: wp-content/themes/myTheme/page-templates/index.php I suppose that with this structure my control pannel should show me the combo to select the template to elect but not working. It is a theme from zero, should I do something else? Any file is required?

Comment: WordPress is looking at .php files that begin with "<?php /* Template Name: Name of template". It will then show "Name of template" as templates on pages. The .php file name can be anything you want. If in your example index.php has a comment like this, then it should be used as a tempate. If it does not, then it will be ignored.

Comment: Problem solved. I had to use "include get_template_directory()" to call my php from the subdirectory. Thanks a lot.